# Count the data inside Map conditionally

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `Map<String, List<String>>`

First I want to know the total count in the values list. (Can be done using for loop but I don't want to use it. Any other good suggestion?)

The next thing which is important I need to compare the count with each value size and see if the count is equal to just the sum of one element or it combines other element as well.

e.g.

```
<"a", 2>
<"b", 0>
<"c", 0>
```

now I want to know that the sum is equal to size of only one element value in the map.

I hope my question is clear.

P.S again can be done using for loops, but any better approach?

Edit:

This is what I came up with. Any other better solutions will be appreciaed

```
    Map<String, Object> mapData = (Map<String, Object>) this.data;
    Map<String, Integer> dataCount = new HashMap<>(mapData.keySet().size());
    int totalCount = 0;
    for (String key: mapData.keySet()) {
        List tempList = (List)mapData.get(key);
        if (tempList != null) {
            totalCount += tempList.size();
            dataCount.put(key, tempList.size());
        }
    }

    if (dataCount.keySet().size() > 1) {
       // Means total count is combination of multiple items
    } else {
       // Means total count is only one item.
    }
```

Comment: ok sir. so what have you tried yet?

Comment: [`List.size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29) - no `for` loop required.

Comment: What's so terrible about for loops ?

Comment: Not so clear, no. "I want to know the total count in the values list." Do you mean you want to know how many elements each `List` contains? Or the total elements in all of the `Lists` in the entire `Map`?

Comment: @RamanShrivastava it would appear that he's tried `for` loops :-)

Comment: but no code posted with where in code he faced problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams:

```
int sum = map.values().stream().mapToInt(List::size).sum();
```

and to check if the sum come from just one entry, logically that means there is exactly one non-zero length list:

```
boolean fromOne = map.values().stream()
    .map(List::size).filter(i -> i > 0).count() == 1;
```

Comment: A stream will still iterate the list, so execution-wise it's no different than a `for` loop. If the only goal is to not write a `for` loop, you could also suggest a `while` loop or a recursive call. Granted, streams are more concise and can be made parallel, but still...

Comment: Using `parallelStream()` rather than `stream()` permits parallel processing. `stream()` is inherently sequential (per JavaDoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream--). But until OP tells us _why_ he doesn't like `for` loops I don't know if parallel processing matters to him.